# Why does 3'x3 LED strip consume more wattage than 9'?

Tags: led-strip

I can't get datasheets on these specific products, but I'm hoping there is a generic answer -- like is the length of the strip's internal wiring just causing enough of a voltage drop over the longer length?

[These](https://www.ledsupply.com/led-strips/non-waterproof-12v-led-strips) high density strips are 60 x 5050 SMD LEDS per meter, cuttable every 3 LEDS, or 2".  I'm assuming these means the strip is constructed with 3 LEDS in series, these groups  in parallel.

Why is a 3' strip rated for 14.2 watts and a 9' strip rated only ~2X at 27.2 watts?   I no longer have a 9' strip, but when I did 3 x 3' strips in parallel, I can confirm through a killawatt that the power supply draws 48 watts.  I expected ~27 watts due to the table claiming that 9' of LEDs would be 27watts.

[image]
[image]

Comment: "Serial" resistance is higher for 9'... than for 3' ?

Comment: @Antonio51 So basically the internal resistance of the wires (not components)   I'm surprised it makes that much of a difference!

Comment: I am also surprised because the first LEDs which are powered "should" be "more" lighted ...